# How to print/scan Underscores in Numeric Literals

Tags: java-7

Team,

I am not able to use the Java 7 [*Underscores in Numeric Literals*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html) feature for getting the input from user and printing out in same format as declared. Please help in doing that? OR Is this feature is incomplete?

```
Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
int x = 1_00_000;
System.out.print( "Enter numeric literals with underscores: " ); //2_00_000
x = input.nextInt();    //java.util.InputMismatchException
System.out.println(x);  // Prints in normal format, but want to be in 2_00_000.
```

NOTE: In Eclipse; I am able to change the value of numeric literal with Underscored numeric literal in runtime. This may be hack, but this is needed feature to input Underscored numeric literal in runtime rit?.

http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/ui/r3_8/Java7news/whats-new-java-7.html#miscellaneous

Comment: Do you think 1_00_000 is valid integer?

Comment: @almasshaikh For readablity purpose, Why i should not want that readablilty in my log files and while inserting the values from other files?

Comment: For Readability purpose you want java to change numbers from string? Then why would you have number formatter?

Comment: @almasshaikh I think we can't use Number formatter to print the Underscores in numeric literal? is any support added in Java7?

Comment: @SMA Yes, `1_00_000` is indeed a valid integer: 100000. See [this example code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/Q3k9bT): `int i = 1_00_000 ;`. And see [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html).

Answer (score 0):

if you want maintain the underscores you can use String:

```
  Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
  System.out.print( "Enter numeric literals with underscores: " ); //2_00_000
  String stringLiterals = input.nextLine();    
  System.out.println(stringLiterals);  // Prints 2_00_000.
```

Comment: Thanks, However how to change this String to Number to work further and again print this number back to same string format..?